# Upgrading Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Enterprise

Tags: windows-8

I have a volumn license with Microsoft, and would like to upgrade my new Windows 7 Ultimate machine, to Windows 8 Enterprise, which should work well my company's AD network.  I don't believe there's an upgrade path, which will retain all of my settings, etc, so I'll have to do a wipe-and-load.  I'm assuming that at some point, during the process, I can tell it to delete the partition and re-create it.  Is there anything else I need to do to flatten my machine to install Windows 8 Enterprise, or is that it?

Comment: Just wipe hdd and install Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions), you cannot upgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Enterprise. As far as I know, this only means that the installer is not able to do a "soft" upgrade which keeps all your files, settings, etc., but will instead do a "hard" upgrade which wipes Windows 7 Ultimate and then installs itself, or you can install it alongside it, keeping Windows 7 intact. This, of course, is not possible if you're dealing with some sort of upgrade-only solution, which requires an existing compatible OS.

I would suggest you do the following:

- Back up all your important files.
- Run the Windows 8 Enterprise installation.
- There should be a point where you have the option to manage your hard drive partitions.
- At that point, you should be able to wipe the Windows 7 Ultimate partition, and use the freed up space to install Windows 8 Enterprise instead.
- Complete the installation.
- Move your files back onto your PC.
- Enjoy! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Transferring user settings should work by using the Windows 7 Migration wizard - to copy files and settings to an external drive - and then use windows 8 "Easy Transfer" to read them back.
Here's [one person's blog on doing it this way](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/transfer-files-settings-from-windows-7-to-windows-8/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Easy Transfer to backup your files and settings from Windows 7, then wipe, re-install, and restore your files and settings.